# Xamrin Forms: How to read the details of a file stored in device's external storage?

Tags: file, xamarin.forms, android-external-storage

I have implemented creating a folder and file in the device's external storage and writing data into that file using this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66469608/xamarin-forms-how-to-create-folder-and-a-file-in-device-external-storage).

**Now I am trying to get the details of the file. For that, I have added a new function in the interface like below.**

```
//Interface
public interface IAccessFile
{
    void CreateFile(string text);
    Java.IO.File GetFileDetails();
}

//Android implementation
public Java.IO.File GetFileDetails()
{
    string rootPath = Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory.AbsolutePath;
    var filePathDir = Path.Combine(rootPath, "StockPDT");
    if (File.Exists(filePathDir))
    {
        string filePath = Path.Combine(filePathDir, "STOCK.TXT");
        Java.IO.File file = new Java.IO.File(filePath);
        return file;
    }
    else
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

But the problem is with the interface function part, getting below error":

> The type or namespace name 'Java' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Screenshot:

[image]

If I return the file from the android part like above, it is easy to get the file details in the portable project. Instead of File, I try to return the file path, but it is empty. **Is there any other way to get the file details other than this?**

Comment: Are you putting the interface and the implementation in the same project?

Comment: @heinst The interface is in the main project(.net project) and implementation is on the android project.

Comment: That’s where your problem was. you can only reference Android types, methods, etc in an Android specific project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the notes in question, I tried to fetch the file details using its path.

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/319908/xamrin-forms-how-to-read-the-details-of-a-file-sto.html

```
//Interface
public interface IAccessFile
{
    string GetFileDetails();
}

//Android implementation
public string GetFileDetails()
{
    string rootPath = Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory.AbsolutePath;
    var filePathDir = Path.Combine(rootPath, "StockPDT");
    if (!File.Exists(filePathDir))
    {
        Directory.CreateDirectory(filePathDir);
    }
    string filePath = Path.Combine(filePathDir, "STOCK.TXT");
    return filePath;
}

//Main Project:
string path = DependencyService.Get<IAccessFile>().GetFileDetails();
string fileDetails = File.ReadAllText(path);
```